# ExpressJS paired with AngularJS Routing without hashtag on links

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement a routing function on my ExpressJS Server.

```
http://localhost:3000/app/sub_one
http://localhost:3000/app/sub_two
```

Unfortunately, I am able to make this work with a prefix of `#` in between the application name and the module. I've been searching for the solution and it seems this code would do it in my angular config - `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`.

But having that implemented and adjusting the link, access the following link returns an unusual behaviour.

```
http://localhost:3000/app/sub_one => Cannot GET /app/sub_one
http://localhost:3000/app/sub_two => Cannot GET /app/sub_two
```

I may have the intuition that the problem is my routing on the `server.js`.

```
var port = 3000;
var express = require("express");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var server = express();

server.use(morgan("tiny"));
server.use("/app", express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
server.use("/bower_components", express.static(__dirname + "/bower_components"));
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Node server initialized. Server's port: " + port);
});
```

I have placed a repository for this problem on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dpebadiola/node-angularjs)

Comment: I'm not an angularjs expert but doesn't angular routing only work with `#`?

Comment: It was before. But if you implement `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, if can work. I've seen it work in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uhZCc0j9RY) on Youtube

Comment: Then you need to serve `index.html` for every request to the app directory (or alle the routes where angular does the routing if it's not the whole folder), because `sub_one` is not a file available in the directory you're specifying in the middleware.

Comment: Well I'm trying to make it work. Unfortunately, I can't find the write configuration to my `server.js` to make it work. Can you help me in the configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Just use a custom middleware, something like this: `server.use('/app', function(req, res, next){ res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');});`

Comment: The solution only get rid of the `Cannot GET /app/sub_one` error. But now, it failed to load the resources (css/js).

Comment: do both then. First `server.use("/app", express.static(__dirname + "/app"));` for all the files in `/app`, then `server.use('/app', function(req, res, next){ res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');});` for every file that is not found by the first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The console is now clear. Now, the angular routing is not working.

Comment: provide your code then how are we supposed to guess?

Comment: I have provided the code by repository. Here's the link for the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/dpebadiola/node-angularjs).

Comment: add it to the question please (the parts that are relevant now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be wrong about this, but it seems that you may be confusing client side routes with server side routes.

Routes defined via `ngRouter` are not supposed to hit server at all.

I modified your code to make it work. It should be enough to let you go on your own -- if you have any questions, give me a shout.

[Forked repo with below changes.](https://bitbucket.org/unao/node-angularjs/)

Files after the changes:

#### config.js

```
var angular = angular.module("NodeAngularJSRouting", ["ngRoute"]);

angular.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/app/sub_one", {
            templateUrl: "/view/sub_view_one/list.html",
            controller: "SubViewOneCtrl" })
        .when("/app/sub_two", {
            templateUrl: "/view/sub_view_two/list.html" })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: "/view/default/default.html",
            controller: "DefaultCtrl" });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

#### server.js

```
var port = 3000;
var express = require("express");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var server = express();

server.use(morgan("tiny"));

// serve bower components statically
server.use("/bower_components", express.static(__dirname + "/bower_components"));

// for all routes defined on client side send
// entry point to the app
// btw. changes of those routes on client side
// are not supposed to hit server at all (!)
server.use("/app*", function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/main.html');
});

// for all public requests try to use /app folder
server.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/app"));

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Node server initialized. Server's port: " + port);
});
```

#### index.html

renamed to main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="NodeAngularJSRouting" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <title>Node AngularJS Routing</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/view/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/app">Node AngularJS Route</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/app/sub_one">View One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/app/sub_two">View Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <div class="container" ng-view></div>

        <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="/config/config.js"></script>
        <script src="/controller/default-default.js"></script>
        <script src="/controller/sub-one_list.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right. I may have confused the routes between the server and client side. Anyways. Is there a way that I could omit `/app/*` on the client side routes?

Comment: @KaidoShugo sure, it is possible -- updated the repo with possible solution.

Comment: @KaidoShugo if this answers your question please accept.